# springcloud-alibaba-starter 2.2.5 pom.xml dependency nacos 1.4.1, in fact but nacos version is 1.1.4,

Tags: nacos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmbMf.png)
above image is mvn:dependency:tree screenshot,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXdgj.png)

this is image is spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-anacos-config.pom source screenshot,
why the nacos-client verison is 1.1.4,but its not 1.4.1?
I research the https://github.com/alibaba/spring-cloud-alibaba/ issues, dont find the answer,
who can know it, please explain why,Thanks!!!